# How to improve this "Minimum Window Substring" solution in Scala?

Tags: string, algorithm, scala

I am solving [Minimum Window Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring) problem using [sliding window](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/sliding-window-algorithm) technique.

The problem is ranked "hard" on Leetcode but the solution is straightforward : for each `right` index in `s.indices` move `left` index while the window `s.slice(left, right + 1)` contains all chars of `t` and keep the minimum `window`. We can write it with `s.indices.foldLeft` to move `right` index and a nested tail-recursive call to move `left` index.

```scala
def minWindow(s: String, t: String): String = {

  // all chars of "t"; maps each char to its count in "t"
  val map = t.groupBy(identity).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.length }

  case class Acc(winMap: Map[Char, Int], window: String, left: Int)
  s.indices.foldLeft(Acc(Map(), "", 0)) { case (acc, right) =>

    val winMap = acc.winMap.updated(s(right), acc.winMap.getOrElse(s(right), 0) + 1)

    def moveLeft(acc: Acc): Acc = {
      val isGood = map.forall { case (k, v) => acc.winMap.get(k).exists(_ >= v) }
      if (isGood) { // the window contains all chars of "t"
        val winMap = acc.winMap.updated(s(acc.left), acc.winMap(s(acc.left)) - 1)
        val window = if (acc.window.isEmpty || acc.window.length > right - acc.left + 1)
          s.slice(acc.left, right + 1)
        else acc.window
        moveLeft(Acc(winMap, window, acc.left + 1))
      } else acc
    }
    moveLeft(acc.copy(winMap = winMap))

  }.window
}
```

This solution is accepted but its performance is poor (20%). Rewriting the solution imperatively did not improve it much (30%). How would you suggest improve it and maybe simplify the code ?

Comment: Note that Leetcode's solution ranker can be a bit broken - I got top-15% and bottom-20% with the same solution in different runs.

Comment: Interesting ... I tried this solution a few times and got same results (bottom 20%). I guess `isGood` calculation is suboptimal and can be improved somehow ...

Comment: You are assuming `map` is small ... but it doesn't have to be. Traversing it multiple times on every iteration may be taxing. Instead of counting everything that is in the window and checking if all counters are correct it may be more efficient to keep track of what's _not_ in the window, - then `isGood` becomes just `foo.isEmpty`, which is constant time. Just a thought ... 
Also (not really a "systemic" improvement, but might make sense for some of the leetcode's test cases) might help to take advantage of the fact that the smallest window will always start and end with a char from `t`

Comment: How is this supposed to be O(n + m) with the `foldLeft` and nested recursion?

Comment: Note: for performance purpose, you should use lower level data structure (primitive data, array of primitive instead of case class, and almost all collections) and lower level api (while instead of foreach).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin the nested recursion moves `left` index only forward (it does not start from the beginning of the array). So the `foldLeft` _and_ the nested recursion together take `O(n)` iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution which beats 100%:

[image]

```
def minWindow(s: String, t: String): String = {
    val cnt = Array.ofDim[Int](128)
    t foreach { c => cnt(c.toInt) -= 1 }
    def move(start: Int, end: Int, covered: Int, left: Int, right: Int): String = 
        if (end == s.length) s.slice(left, right)
        else {
            cnt(s(end).toInt) += 1
            val newCovered = if (cnt(s(end).toInt) <= 0) covered + 1 else covered
            var newStart = start
            while (newStart < end && cnt(s(newStart).toInt) > 0) {
                cnt(s(newStart).toInt) -= 1
                newStart += 1
            }
            if (newCovered == t.length && (right == 0 || right - left >= end - newStart + 1))
                move(newStart, end + 1, newCovered, newStart, end + 1)
            else move(newStart, end + 1, newCovered, left, right)
        }

    move(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тhe [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75955507/521070) made me realize that I should use a map of all chars in `t` along with their frequencies and the number of these chars in the current window.

Another useful technique is to initialize the map with *negative* chars frequencies (I've tried a map with positive frequencies but it made the solution much more complex).

So I re-wrote the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75955507/521070) with `foldLeft` and immutable `map` and the performance was great (top 10%)

```
def minWindow(s: String, t: String): String = {

  val map = t.groupBy(identity).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.length * (-1) }
  case class Acc(map: Map[Char, Int], covered: Int, left: Int, win: String)
  s.indices.foldLeft(Acc(map, covered = 0, left = 0, win = "")) { case (acc, right) =>

    // add new char s(right) to the current window
    val map = acc.map.updated(s(right), acc.map.getOrElse(s(right), 0) + 1)
    val covered = if (map.getOrElse(s(right), 0) <= 0) acc.covered + 1 else acc.covered

    // move the left boundary of the window while it is "good" 
    def moveLeft(map: Map[Char, Int], left: Int): (Map[Char, Int], Int) = {
      lazy val count = map.getOrElse(s(left), 0)
      if (left < right && count > 0)
        moveLeft(map.updated(s(left), count - 1), left + 1)
      else (map, left)
    }
    val (newMap, left) = moveLeft(map, acc.left)

    // store the window if it is "good" and shorter than the previous one
    val isGood = covered == t.length
    val win = if (isGood && (acc.win.isEmpty || acc.win.length > right - left + 1))
      s.slice(left, right + 1) else acc.win

    Acc(newMap, covered, left, win)
  }.win
}
```